# javascript calulator display: output displaying computed calculation with "=" sign instead of just computed value

Tags: javascript

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
var display = document.getElementById('display');

buttons.forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.addEventListener('click', addToScreen, answer);
});

function addToScreen() {
    var val = this.getAttribute('value');
    if (val == '=') {
        answer();
    }
    console.log(val);
    display.value += val;
}
function answer() {
    val = display.value;
    val = eval(val);
    display.value = "";
    display.value += val;
}
```

Hi All,
so these are my two functions that display and compute the calculation for the calculator.
however there are a couple of problems I am running. the first is that when a calculation is performed the out is a number with an equal sign for eg. 8*8 the display would be `64=`. how can I get rid of the "=" sign. 
second problem is with my if`val=='='` statement. The statement causes the program to jump to the answer function which has `eval(val)` statement. however if a user enters "=" as the first input/second this would display undefined on the display calculator screen. how can I fix these two issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return after you call answer() inside the addToScreen function

```
function addToScreen() {
    var val = this.getAttribute('value');
    if (val == '=') {
        answer();
        return;
    }
    console.log(val);
    display.value += val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the fix.